# Обработка javascript запросов на сервере python

Tags: javascript, python

Имеется простой вебсокет сервер на python.

```js
import socket
import json

dictionary = {'Hello':'World'}
dictionary_json = json.dumps(hardware)

def parse_request(request):
 try:
  parsed = request.split()
  method = parsed[0]
  url = parsed[1]
  return (method, url)
 except:
  pass

def generate_headers(method, url):
 if not method == "GET":
  return ('HTTP/1.1 405 Method not allowed\n\n', 405)
 return ('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n', 200)

def generate_content(code, url):
 if code == 404:
  return '<h1>404</h1><p>Not found</p>'
 if code == 405:
  return '<h1>405</h1><p>Method not allowed</p>'
 return dictionary_json

def generate_respose(request):
 method, url = parse_request(request)
 headers, code = generate_headers(method, url)
 body = generate_content(code, url)
 return (headers + body).encode()


def run_server():
 server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
 server_socket.bind(('localhost', 8080))
 server_socket.listen()
 while True:
  client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
  request = client_socket.recv(1024)
  print(request)
  response = generate_respose(request.decode('utf-8'))
  print(response)
  client_socket.sendall(response)
  client_socket.close()
```

Если открыть браузер и перейти по localhost:8080, то выведется содержимое dictionary_json на экране. Я бы хотел, чтобы содержимое словаря выводилось по запросу javascript. То есть простая html страничка с кнопкой, по нажатию которой выводилось бы на экране содержимое словаря.

Вопрос собственно в том как можно это реализовать самым простым образом? Я так понимаю нужно использовать ajax запросы и тд, но тогда как их обрабатывать сервером?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Имеется простой вебсокет сервер на python.
>
> ```
> import socket
> ```

распространённая ошибка, это не "WebSocket".

---

если вам действительно хочется использовать WS - читайте дальше.

Внимание, рекомендуемая библиотека, а так же приведённый код мной не проверялись, это первая попавшаяся ссылка из гугла (https://pypi.org/project/websockets/).

следующий ниже текст является вольным переводом **части статьи** ["Getting started"](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#browser-based-example), а именно раздела "Browser-based example".

### Requirements

Python ≥ 3.4(лучше Python ≥ 3.6).

### Installation

установите зависимости следующей командой

```
pip install websockets
```

### Browser-based example

это пример как запустить WebSocket сервер и подключиться к нему из браузера

запустите этот скрипт из консоли

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# WS server that sends messages at random intervals

import asyncio
import datetime
import random
import websockets

async def time(websocket, path):
    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'
        await websocket.send(now)
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random() * 3)

start_server = websockets.serve(time, '127.0.0.1', 5678)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

затем создайте `index.html` файл со следующим содержанием и откройте его в браузере (пр. от пер.: попробуйте просто перетащить файл в браузер)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WebSocket demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:5678/"),
                messages = document.createElement('ul');
            ws.onmessage = function (event) {
                var messages = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],
                    message = document.createElement('li'),
                    content = document.createTextNode(event.data);
                message.appendChild(content);
                messages.appendChild(message);
            };
            document.body.appendChild(messages);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, этот метод работает. А есть возможность устанавливать между сервером и клиентом ssl соединение? Просто если вместо:

var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:5678/")

Написать: 

var ws = new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.1:5678/")

В консоли javascript выходит ошибка:

index.html:55 WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:5678/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: [secure-example](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#secure-example)

Comment: Ага, увидел, буду разбираться.
Единственное с какой проблемой я столкнулся еще, это с завершением работы сервера. 
asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()
asyncio.get_event_loop().close()
ничего не завершают.
sys.exit() - тоже не помогает
Хотелось бы как-то завершать работу сервера и скрипта полностью и корректно. В документации я этого чего-то не нашел.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь вызвать метод close на вспомогательной библиотеке а не на сокете. Попробуйте 'start_server.close()' подробнее смотрите документацию, слева конопочка api

Comment: [websockets.server.WebSocketServer.close](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#websockets.server.WebSocketServer.close)

Comment: Разобрался, большое спасибо!

Comment: Как найти в документации что-то похожее на вот такую штуку из библиотеки обычных сокетов?
socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
Просто мне нужно сделать так, чтобы, если соединение разрывалось, оно восстанавливалось на том же порту (если вдруг соединение разорвано, а скрипт висит в процессах)

Comment: 1) разорвалось из разряда шнур выдернул и вставил ? 2) создайте пожалуйста отдельный вопрос с метками [ws] [js] [python] , если есть простой минимальные пример - приложите его к вопросу. 3) ну и ссылочку сюда, в комментарии, чтобы я посмотрел напишите

Comment: Я так и не разобрался в том как нормально останавливать, создал отдельный вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/954521/Адекватная-остановка-сервера-и-закрытие-всех-процессов-websockets