# Адекватная остановка сервера и закрытие всех процессов - Websockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, asyncio

Имеется файл server.py, в котором есть класс Server, который создаёт и запускает простейший вебсокет сервер:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    async def send_data(self, websocket, path):
        try:
            async for message in websocket:
                data = json.loads(message)
                if data['type'] == 'get' and data['action'] == 'OK':
                    message = json.dumps({'status': 'OK'})
                    await websocket.send(message)
                elif data['type'] == 'get' and data['action'] == 'CANCEL':
                    message = json.dumps({'status': 'CANCEL'})
                    await websocket.send(message)
                elif data['type'] == 'post':
                    message = json.dumps({'status': 'success'})
                    await websocket.send(message)
        except Exception as msg:
            logging.debug(msg)


    def run_server(self):
        start_server = websockets.serve(self.send_data, 'localhost', 8080)
        self.loop.run_until_complete(start_server)
        self.loop.run_forever()
```

Также есть main.py, где сервер запускается:

```
from server import Server

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = Server()
    server.run_server()
```

Проблема в том, что никак не получается остановить работу сервера и завершить все потоки из кода (только через диспетчер задач). Также из-за того что нормально все закрыть не получается, постоянно при перезапуске сервера возникает ошибка, что порт занят:
[Errno 10048] error while attempting to bind on address ('::1', 8080, 0, 0)

Каким образом я могу осуществить полную остановку сервера? В консоли хотя бы по сочетанию клавиш ctrl+C, например. В будущем будет GUI, в котором мне нужно будет делать это по нажатию кнопки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    async def send_data(self, websocket, path):
        ...

    async def serve(self, stop):
        async with websockets.serve(self.send_data, 'localhost', 8080):
            await stop

    def run_server(self):
        stop = asyncio.Future()
        self.loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGTERM, stop.set_result, None)
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.serve(stop))
```

[Соответствующий раздел документации](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deployment.html#graceful-shutdown).

**UPD:** Костыли для Windows

```
def run_server(self):
    async def ticker(delay):
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(delay)

    stop = asyncio.Future()
    ticker_task = asyncio.ensure_future(ticker(3))  # Проверять Ctrl+C каждые 3 секунды
    try:
        self.loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([
            self.serve(stop),
            ticker_task
        ]))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        stop.set_result(None)
        ticker_task.cancel()
        self.loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(5))  # 5 секунд ждать завершения работы
    finally:
        self.loop.close()
```

Comment: Такая реализация выдает ошибку в строке: self.loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGTERM, stop.set_result, None). Ошибка такого рода:   File "C:\Python\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 499, in add_signal_handler
    raise NotImplementedError

Comment: Возможно это связано с тем, что я пытаюсь это сделать  в Windows. Каким образом можно осуществить на винде?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35772001/4794368